# Polar plot and Pie chart in swift For Tensorflow

Tags: arrays, swift3, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to draw the **polar plot, histogram, and Pie chart** in sift for TensorFlow if than show the process?

Answer (score 1):

Swift for TensorFlow includes python interoperability.

https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/python_interoperability

See how they just use matplotlib:

```
let np = Python.import("numpy")
let plt = Python.import("matplotlib.pyplot")

let time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
let amplitude = np.exp(-0.1 * time)
let position = amplitude * np.sin(3 * time)

plt.figure(figsize: [15, 10])

plt.plot(time, position)
plt.plot(time, amplitude)
plt.plot(time, -amplitude)

plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Position (m)")
plt.title("Oscillations")

plt.show()
```

[`plt.polar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.polar.html) and [`plt.pie`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) should just work.